# ruby on rails soft deleting is not working properly and it is included in queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soft-delete

I am begginer wirh ruby on rails and start working on an already designed webapp build with ruby on rails (ruby v3.0.4 and rails v7.0.4).
Recently I noticed that soft deleted records are now displayed in my index list. I checked my postgress table and I can see that the column deleted_at is populated correctly for soft deleted records and not null as before.
For example, Usually if I apply simple queries as `Submit.count` or `Submit.where("id >?", value)`, soft deleted records are not included in the output of the query. This has recently changed and I am not sure why and how to solve that.
What could be the reason behind this change? can anyone help me with some explanation.

Here are some of the gems used in this webapp:
active_interaction (5.2.0), activemodel (7.0.4), activesupport (7.0.4), paranoia (2.6.1), zeitwerk (2.6.6), cancancan (3.4.0)

Comment: yes this line "acts_as_paranoid" is there

Comment: Can you post: The `Submit` model, an area where the query is unfiltered (probably a controller action) and the relevant logs for a request to that action showing the request and the SQL queries executed? This will allow us a much better opportunity to debug your current issue.

Comment: ...it'd also be great for you to show a `rails console` session running those queries, and the SQL that's generated.